# UITableView in iOS 7 not scrolling to correct location when editing UITextView in cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uitextview, nslayoutmanager

I have a table view with static cells. One cell contains a `UITextView` and the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is calculated dynamically so that the cell is always tall enough to accomodate the text (that part took some work under iOS 7, actually, as it's no longer possible to simply ask the textView for its `contentSize`).

When I tap within the text view to start editing, the keyboard animates into place, the contentInsets on the tableView are automatically adjusted to account for this (ie, bottom inset of 216px for iPhone portrait orientation), the cursor / caret becomes visible, and then the table view *scrolls to another location*. It ends up looking like a bounce.

Here's a video of this in the simulator: https://www.dropbox.com/s/htdbb0t7985u6n4/textview-bounce.mov

Notice that for a second the caret is just above the keyboard. I've been logging the table view's `contentOffset` and I can see it scroll to a nice value and then suddenly "turn around" and scroll back.

Oddly, if I turn on slow animations in the simulator the problem disappears; the `contentOffset` reversal doesn't happen and things work as I expect (ie, iOS 6 behavior).

Here's the video with slow animations: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhn7vspx86t4exb/textview-nobounce.mov

Implementation notes:

- The text view is pink and has AutoLayout constraints that keep it pinned to the cell at distance 0 (except left side, which is 10pts)
- I'm using `boundingRectWithSize:` to calculate the table view height, adjusting for lineFragmentPadding and any top/bottom insets. Seems to work.
- I have set the textView to not be scrollable, but didn't notice anything different when `scrollEnabled` == YES
- This is a table view controller and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` == YES

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, I've tracked it to the contentSize of the UITableView being reset after I do a UITableView beginupdates and endupdates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to adjust UITableView frame when keyboard appears. Call `[self attachKeyboardHelper]` in viewWillAppear and `[self detachKeyboardHelper]` in viewWillDisappear.

```
- (void)attachKeyboardHelper{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)detachKeyboardHelper{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    // Animate up or down
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
    if(self.view==self.tableView){
        CGRect newTableFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-keyboardFrame.size.height);
        self.tableView.frame = newTableFrame;
    }else{
        CGRect newTableFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-self.tableView.frame.origin.y-keyboardFrame.size.height);
        self.tableView.frame = newTableFrame;
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];


    CGRect newTableFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.view.superview.bounds.size.height-self.tableView.frame.origin.y);
    self.tableView.frame = newTableFrame;
    if(newTableFrame.size.height>self.tableView.contentSize.height-self.tableView.contentOffset.y){
        float newOffset=MAX(self.tableView.contentSize.height-newTableFrame.size.height, 0);
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, newOffset) animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: The answer got much better with some example. Good for newbies that are trying to find answers here ;-)